# Flexicious radioButtonMode

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, flexicious

Flexicious added a radioButtonMode property to its FlexDataGridCheckBoxColumn component. It looks like a radio button but doesn't act like one because it allows me to select each row of data.

Am I missing something? Do I need to write custom code to accomplish this or can I define a groupName somewhere?

How do I make a flexicious grid single select?

Any tips are greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried setting selectionMode="singleRow"? If you need additional assistance, reach out to our support and we will be glad to help you out!

Comment: Thank you, that was easy. I'm brand new to the flexicious grid so I'm just getting up to speed.